# Create a Ionic local webserver to upload files inside my App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I would to implement a backup system inside a offline only/first Ionic app. I would to create a backup json file and then upload it across computers browsers through web URL that my app released, like Airdroid and others examples.
What do you suggest me?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I found a HTTP server implementation for Cordova apps. Might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd

If you are after a WebSocket server for Cordova apps: https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-websocket-server

Or if you want to make a native app like AirDroid (opens a port and listens for connections from other devices) this article might come in handy:
http://www.whycouch.com/2012/12/how-to-create-android-app-like-airdroid.html

Answer (score 0):

For backup either use PHP to store your data but there is a better solution called FireBase at http://firebase.com/ it syncs your data automatically give it your documentation a look

Comment: My app is offline first and contains personal data. it means that I can't upload data to Firebase, Parse or other baas/cloud service without the user autorization. Users, when they are online, can only sends an e-mail with a backup json file. Then I would to launch a web server and through a computer browser put my json file into the app. How can I launch a local web server from my Ionic app? Any idea to store backup file without cloud service?

Comment: you cannot launch a server as the app is on the client side so it cannot do that...u could write a php script for getting the data..or firebase and use the firebase authentication...you can launch a web "Browser" take a loot at the in-app-browser here  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser